# Texstudio worked out-of-the-box, but now I don't know how to add packages

Tags: packages, texstudio

So, I've installed Texstudio on an virtual machine with Ubuntu on it... And somehow it worked (i.e. compiled, built etc a project I worked on previously) without installing either MikTex or TexLive. It seems that it has no problem using amsmath.sty or graphicx.sty, but, obviously, it doesn't know what to do with some other packages (in particular I want to add physics.sty).

Rather than sitting through the entire MikTex/TexLive instalation (which would waste me half a day), I would rather just download this sty file and add it by hand. My problem is that I have no idea where to put it, especially since I'm not familiar at all with the Linux folders. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Place the sty files in your project folder, i.e. the folder containing your main `.tex` document. However, I would strongly advise to install a tex distribution, since many packages depend on others and adding all by hand becomes very cumbersome.

Comment: My guess is that there is already a full TeX distribution somewhere on your system. Why? It's because TeXstudio is a front end to a TeX distribution; by itself, TeXstudio cannot compile anything. If you look at the log file of a successfully completed compilation run, you should be able to figure out which TeX distribution is around. This should tell you what you may need to do in terms of either updating or upgrading your TeX distribution.